# Logging with JSON GELF format in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2, logback, gelf

I'm using Spring Boot and would like to have this code:

```
LOG.info("Scheduled appointment for user 12345 [appointment ID 100]");
```

Produce the following log message in JSON GELF format:

```
{
  "version": "1.1",
  "host": "hostname.ec2.internal",
  "short_message": "Scheduled appointment for user 12345 [appointment ID 100]",
  "timestamp": 1318280136,
  "level": 1,
  "_user": "user@acme.com",
  "_clientip": "127.0.0.1",
  "_env": "prod",
  "_app":"scheduler"
}
```

Do I need to create my own logger for this or can I customize Logback/Log4j2 to behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Log4j 2.x perspective, you can use the [JSON Layout Template](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html), which has a built-in [`eventTemplate`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#event-templates) for GELF.

Your appender configuration in the `log4j2-spring.xml` file would look like:

```xml
<Console name="CONSOLE">
    <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:GelfLayout.json" />
</Console>
```

**Remark**: Since Spring Boot uses Logback as default logging system, you'll have to exclude the `spring-boot-starter-logging` and replace it with [`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2).

Moreover the JSON Layout Template requires an additional dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
</dependency>
```